# Terminal Command build xcode project for 64 bit with all other also

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, xcode5, xcodebuild

I am using below command :

```
xcodebuild -project $PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj -scheme $PROJECT_NAME -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug
xcodebuild -project $PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj -scheme $PROJECT_NAME -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug
```

for building the application it's working but I need to build our application with iphone/ipad retina 64 bit but it' not working.

for combining

```
lipo -create "${WS_DIR}/Build/Debug-iphoneos/libRPCCore.a" "${WS_DIR}/Build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCore.a" -output "${WS_DIR}/Build/RPCLib/libCore.a"
```

I am not able to build the application for ipad/ipahone retina 64 bit application using terminal command. please help to create the build script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is because you have *Build Active Architecture Only* set for Debug mode, which is the default setting I believe.  This is because there is no need to build for all architectures during debugging as the build is expected to run only on the device being used for debugging.

This is normally turned off for release and you can test this from the command line by using `-configuration Release`.

BTW I don't believe you need to specify the `-sdk` option to `xcodebuild` as the build settings should have that covered.